# Codeigniter Session Library not working while integrate wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, session

I have codeigniter application in sub-domain main and wordprees installed in root domain.

- www.example.com - wordpress
- www.example.com/sub - codeigniter

I'm Using Version 3.1.6 codeigniter. So I did on codeigniter main index file like this

```
 require_once('../wp-blog-header.php'); // Load Wordpress
```

All wordpress function working well in codeigniter but if i add codeigniter [ionAuth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) then it's throw a error cause ionauth used session library.
or any kind of session retrieve code then it's throw like this error

```
Severity: Warning
Message: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time
Filename: Session/Session.php
Line Number: 316

Backtrace:
```

That mean wordpress session conflict with codeigniter but I also tried wordpress magic quote , it's also not working
I've been follow this [link](https://gist.github.com/philbirnie/4674643/)
 At the end if don't use codeigniter session then every things working well.

Comment: probably because wordpress starts its own session...

Comment: what version of CI, 2.x hates WP.

Comment: What do you use wordpress for, for example can you destroy the wp session, or use its ID in CI,  I don't use CI sessions as we have a membership framework that handles it, we use wordpress but without template support in CI.  Should note, without template support you can still use the wordpress header and other parts manually.  So we use CI + Wordpress + Amember ( wasn't my choice ).

Comment: Why do you think you need to load WordPress ??

Comment: Maybe instead of using Ion Auth, you could do something like this: http://dovy.io/wordpress/authenticating-outside-of-wordpress-on-diff-domain/

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix god help you ;)

Comment: @Alex - it's been running for 3 1/2 years in full production for my company, we have a service that does apx 200 million queries per day,  Using RabbitMq, Sphinx, MongoDB, PHP, Mysql... etc. Our service can do 180k searches per minute.  I'm a wizard ... runs on Azure standard_A8 server 56GB ram and 2 slave servers with 16GB ram each.  Inside a full DMZ with a separate SFTP server, and I think 3 or four other VMs with various junk on them ... lol

Comment: @ Brian Gottier, Why not ?